# Delay the execution of jQuery script for specific time . . 

Tags: jquery

I want to delay the execution of jQuery script for specific time.

For example, I have a user define function `ABC()` and i want to call this function after a few seconds.

my example code is below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var i = $('#test').val();
  //here i want to delay the script for a few second 
  var value =  ABC();    
</script>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `setTimeout`:

```
 var value = null; //set a default value
 setTimeout( function(){
      value =  ABC();
 }, 3000); //3 seconds
```